# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, macos

MacOS 10.12.2でローカルサーバー（PHP7.0.14)でサーバを立ててPHPを勉強しています。

```
<?php

define('DB_DATABASE', 'test_db');    //データベース指定  
define('DB_USERNAME', 'dbuser');     //データベースユーザ
define('DB_PASSWORD', '********');   //データベースパスワード
define('PDO_DSN', 'mysql:dbhost=localhost;dbname=' .DB_DATABASE);    
//   データベースに接続するための文字列

try {
    //connect
    $db = new PDO(PDO_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    //insert
    $db->exec("insert into users (name, score) values ('ryo', '55')");
    echo "user added!";

    //disconnect
    $db = null;
 }catch (PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

このindex.phpにアクセスすると、データベースに情報を追加するというシンプルなコードです
ブラウザから接続すると、SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directoryとエラーが出ます。 
`sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/var/mysql/`
を実行して、PHPもデータベースへのアクセス権を与えたのですがうまくできませんでした。

回答お願いします。

Comment: No such file or directory というエラーなのですから、アクセス権の問題ではなく、ディレクトリの構成、ファイルの配置とphp.iniの内容が整合していないのではないかと思われます。

Answer (score 1):

僕も同じエラーが発生しました。
MySQLが起動していなかったことが原因でした。

```
$ sudo mysql.server start
```

でイケました。

Answer (score 1):

> 注意: Unix のみ
>   ホスト名を `"localhost"` にすると、サーバーへの接続はドメインソケットを使って行われます。
>   libmysqlclient を使って PDO_MYSQL をコンパイルした場合は、ソケットファイルの場所は libmysqlclient のコンパイル時の場所になります。
>   mysqlnd を使って PDO_MYSQL をコンパイルした場合は、デフォルトのソケットは `pdo_mysql.default_socket` の設定を使って作られます。
>   -- http://php.net/manual/ja/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php

上記に引用した事象が発現しているとしたら `No such file or directory` というのはソケットファイルが見つからないという意味ではないでしょうか。

`mysqld` の起動後、ソケットファイルのパスを特定し php.ini で指定するか、
単に `PDO_DSN` に `unix_socket=...` とすることでソケット接続を指定できます。
（`/usr/local/var/mysql` の様なので）仮に MySQL を Homebrew でインストールしたのであれば、ソケットファイルの場所は `/tmp/mysql.sock` だったと思います。

あるいは `host=127.0.0.1` などすることで上記制限に引っかからなくなるかも知れません（未確認です）。

ご確認ください。

---

もう一点

> PDO_MYSQL データソース名（DSN）は以下の要素で構成されます。
>   ...
>   `host`
>   データベースサーバーが存在するホスト名を指定します。
>   -- http://php.net/manual/ja/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php

よって `dbhost=localhost` ではなく `host=localhost` が正しいと思います。
（まあ、正しくした所でソケット接続になってしまうようですが。。。）